# Qt's best way to display very large rich text?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

I need to display very large logs that uses HTML tags for marking different types of data.

Using QTextEdit and QTextBrowser really slows the application, especially on append operations. I would really like to keep the QTextEdit interface and abilities.

I've seen people that implemented their own flavor of TextEdit to improve performance, but I wandered if anyone solved this issue using "Qt" tools. I thought about using the Model/View framework to load data on demand but it is not quite what it was intended for I think.

Maybe subclassing QTextEdit and override some of its slots for scrolling...

If anyone encountered this issue and solved it, I would appreciate some tips.

Thanks.

Comment: Rendering speed has a lot to do with the size of paragraphs because word wrap calculations are expensive. Try inserting extra newline characters, see if that helps, it might be useful to supplement `<p>` and `<br>` with `'\n'`

Comment: It could also help simply to split them up into pages.

Comment: @spraff, any suggestions on how to implement that and if you can give me some details on what exactly do you mean "pages"?

Comment: @spraff, the QTextEdit doesn't consider `\n` as new line character to split paragraphs ?

Comment: There used to be a very strong push toward making humongous scrolling lists.  (I remember back when the windows 32 bit api was coming out and developers were excited about it managing a million list items.)  But users want software that solves their problems, and when you look at today's search engines it shows that giving people a way to query and narrow down the input is more helpful than spewing everything and overloading the machine.  It might be better to show the last N log entries by default (give this as an option), and offer a filter box with some well-written common search features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your log is presumably tabular at some level, then the Model/View framework sounds like it could work for you.  Perhaps you could try using a `QListView` with [QGraphicsTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicstextitem.html), It has methods for setting/getting HTML:

- [QGraphicsTextItem::setHtml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicstextitem.html#setHtml).
- [QGraphicsTextItem::toHtml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicstextitem.html#toHtml)

You'll get some benefits and hassles from writing it that way, but you should certainly be able to finesse the insertions and append speed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `QPlainTextEdit` for large log files -- that's what it was designed for. You don't get the full range of options that `QTextEdit` provides, but you can set the font and the text colour.

Comment: `QPlainTextEdit` is not good for me, I need hypertext links and other rich text features.

Comment: The problem with `QPlainTextEdit` is, surprisingly, closing it. It takes ENORMOUS amount of time to free its internal memory blocks (`QTextBlockData` objects).

Answer (score 0):

why not using `QWebKit`? Module itself is rather heavy, but rendering speed is very good.

Comment: Maybe it will render the page fast, but I need to constantly append lines, and that means reloading the page every append...

Comment: I used it with the same case. I had to use webkit after QTextEdit began laging on scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Since the ROI on re-implementing QTextEdit with the Model/View architecture is low, I will go with @spraff comment on using paging.

Basically I will limit the number of lines I keep in my log, since the log is also dumped into a file, if the user will require something from the past or future (by adding special buttons), I will read it from the file dynamically (lightweight model/view....).