# Qt - Scrolling through large text buffer

Tags: c++, qt, text, qt4, scroll

I have a huge text buffer where each line is generated through a library and I want my QPlainTextEdit widget to be able to load part of it programmatically with my QScrollBar.

Here's what I thought:

- Load each line in a **vector < string >** with **push_back** and store a **count** variable with the total number of lines
- Use the QScrollBar to load its value position + some other lines to fill up the edit box area

This might work but I found that **push**'ing **_back** every line in the vector is awfully slow, even if I **reserve** space for its elements. If I append each line to a **string** that's pretty fast instead, but then I'd need to split each line with the '\n' character.

I need a way to push_back fast or to be able to get n lines in the huge text buffer quickly

Comment: You can look at memory-mapped files. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914147/qts-best-way-to-display-very-large-rich-text

Comment: I'm not sure why appending strings to a vector would be awfully slow. Define 'large'?

Comment: a disassembly of a .text section, so a LOT of lines

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and what you are probably looking for is lazy instantiation. Get the total number of lines in the files. Since your textbox only displays n lines, when the scrollbar goes to position y (line y), then display only lines [y, n+y] from the file

If youd like a little more of a buffer consider breaking the data down into logical pages. I.e. if your 'page' size is 200 lines then when you go to line 300 via the scrollbar you know to load page 2.

Read ing a file line by line is always going to be linear time. But the slow down in the program will be a result of keeping a huge amount of data in memory.